# ImageMagick displays all images as transparent

Tags: linux, imagemagick

Every image I view using `display` from ImageMagick is at about 50% opacity, including the ImageMagick GUI itself:

[image: Transparent ImageMagick GUI]

The KDE window border is not transparent. For the life of me, I cannot find any setting within ImageMagick that changes this. I also cannot find any setting in my system settings that affects the transparency either.

The only application (that I've found) this affects is ImageMagick, so I don't think it's a generic X setting. There don't appear to be any system config files for ImageMagick, and I don't have any obvious ones in my home directory.

I'm using ImageMagick 7.0.7-34 from OpenSUSE Tumbleweed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some recent update fixed this, but I didn't manage to pin down exactly what the cause was.

Very unsatisfying, but at least it's solved!

Answer (score 0):

This issue is related to the current compositor and/or session.
On Wayland Imagemagick always shows either pixelated image or semi-transparent window including canvas.

The easy fix is to use:
1) standard plasma
2) change compositor to XRender (System Settings -> Display and Monitor -> Compositor)

Comment: The problem went away in some recent update, but I don't think I'm using Wayland anyway. This could still be useful if other people have the same symptoms